# Invoked function not returning result in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 functions one is invoking another. The inner invoked function add is checking if in `this.state.selectedBookList` exists `bookName` got from an input field, if not exists its adding `bookName` to `this.state.selectedBookList`, otherwise is returning to function that is invoked by. But I have the problem that the result of `book.selectedBookName === bookName` is always false. that cannot be, and my arr is at the end always empty. Can any check, what is wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EnteredBooks from '.././components/EnteredBooks/EnteredBooks';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            bookName: '',
            bookDescription: '',
            bookUrl: '',
            bookPrice: '',
            enteredBookList: [],
            selectedBookId: '',
            selectedBookName: '',
            selectedBookDescription: '',
            selectedBookUrl: '',
            selectedBookPrice: '',
            selectedBookList: [],
            activeIndex: '',
        }
    }

        submitHandler = (event) => {

            event.preventDefault();

            let bookId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            let bookName = this.state.bookName;
            let bookDescription = this.state.bookDescription;
            let bookUrl = this.state.bookUrl;
            let bookPrice = this.state.bookPrice;


            this.setState({
                enteredBookList: this.state.enteredBookList.concat({bookId, bookName, bookDescription, bookUrl, bookPrice})
            })
        }

     add = (bookName, bookUrl, bookDescription, bookPrice, index) => {
            let arr = this.state.selectedBookList;

            let found = arr.some(book => {
                return book.selectedBookName === bookName;
            });

            if (!found) { 
                return arr.concat({bookName, bookUrl, bookDescription, bookPrice, index}); 
            } 
             console.log(found);
        }

    selectedBookHandler = (bookName, bookUrl, bookDescription, bookPrice, index) => {
        let arr = this.add(bookName, bookUrl, bookDescription, bookPrice, index);

        this.setState({
            selectedBookName: bookName,
            selectedBookUrl: bookUrl,
            selectedBookDescription: bookDescription,
            selectedBookPrice: bookPrice,
            selectedBookId: index
        });
        console.log(this.state.selectedBookList);
    }

    render() {

        const enteredBooks = this.state.enteredBookList.map((enteredBook, index) => {
            const active = this.state.activeIndex;
            return <EnteredBooks
                key={index}
                enteredBook={enteredBook}
                active={index === active} 
                selected={this.selectedBookHandler.bind(this, enteredBook, enteredBook.bookName, enteredBook.bookUrl,
                    enteredBook.bookDescription, enteredBook.bookPrice, index)}
            />
        });

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="add-product">
                   <form>
                        <div>
                            <label>Product name:</label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder="Book" 
                                value={this.state.BookName || ''}
                                onChange={event => this.setState({bookName: event.target.value})}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label>Product description:</label>
                            <textarea 
                                placeholder="Sample description..."
                                value={this.state.bookDescription || ''}
                                onChange={event => this.setState({bookDescription: event.target.value})}
                            >
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label>Product image:</label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder="http://...jpg"
                                value={this.state.bookUrl || ''}
                                pattern="https?://.+" required
                                onChange={event => this.setState({bookUrl: event.target.value})}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label>Product price:</label>
                            <input 
                                type="number" 
                                min="0" 
                                placeholder="20.5" 
                                value={this.state.bookPrice || ''}
                                onChange={event => this.setState({bookPrice: event.target.value})}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            onClick={event => this.submitHandler(event)}
                        >
                            Add a new Task
                        </button>
                    </form>
                 </div>

                 <div className="list-products">
                    <ul>
                       {enteredBooks}
                    </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please post full code for this class, `book` is not defined

Comment: Why `book.selectedBookName` when the parameter is named `watch` (`arr.some(watch => { ...`)?

Comment: _"The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method **does not change the existing arrays**, but instead returns a new array."_

Answer (score 1):

The `.some()` function invoked not using the predicate `watch` to test against each element of the array.

It needs to use the predicate to test against each element by changing `watch` to `book` as follows:

```
let found = arr.some(book => {
  return book.selectedBookName === bookName;
})
```

As @Andreas pointed out below, the `arr.concat` function does not change the change the `state.selectedBookList` array but returns a new one. You will also have to set this to the state once it is returned from `.add` as follows:

```
let arr = this.add(bookName, bookUrl, bookDescription, bookPrice, index);

this.setState({
   selectedBookList: arr,
   selectedBookName: bookName,
   selectedBookUrl: bookUrl,
   selectedBookDescription: bookDescription,
   selectedBookPrice: bookPrice,
   selectedBookId: index
});
```

Also should `let arr = this.state.selectedWatchList;` be `this.state.selectedBookList`?

Comment: But this still won't change the `selectedWatchList` but that's what TO is expecting, at least that's what I think because of the `console.log(this.state.selectedBookList);` at the end

Comment: watch is a typo, as you wrote Anderas it won't change, and I need it changed.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a book and it's not found you are concatenating it to you contextual array `arr` instead of your `selectedWatchlist`.

```
return arr.concat({bookName, bookUrl, bookDescription, bookPrice, index});
```

Should be

```
return this.state.selectedWatchList.concat({bookName, bookUrl, bookDescription, bookPrice, index});
```

Comment: `arr === this.state.selectedWatchList`

Comment: You should not be directly changing the state without using `setState`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet :

`this.state.selectedWatchList is not defined in this.state = {};`

i think you use this.state.selectedWatchList instead of this.state. selectedBookList

`let arr = this.state.selectedWatchList;`

Comment: Watch is typo as you wrote should be this.state. selectedBookList